# tinyxml2 create file using printer

Tags: xml, save, tinyxml2

I am trying to make a xml file using C++ and tinyxml2, to save a games state. Right now I just end up with an empty file, and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("test.xml","w");
XMLPrinter printer(pFile);
printer.OpenElement("Rooms");
printer.OpenElement("room");
printer.PushAttribute("id","RID_DUNGEON_1");
printer.PushAttribute("description","unpleasant dungeon");
printer.PushAttribute("name","dungeon");
printer.OpenElement("items");
printer.OpenElement("item");
printer.PushAttribute("id","torch");
printer.CloseElement();
printer.CloseElement();
printer.CloseElement();
printer.CloseElement();
```

The end result should be something like this:

```
<Rooms>
    <room id="RID_DUNGEON_1" description="unpleasant dungeon" name="dungeon">
        <items>
            <item id="torch"/>
        </items>
    </room>
</Rooms>
```

Comment: I try your code and it's working as you expect. You should check if fopen succeeded and you should close the file using fclose(pFile) in order to flush.

Comment: Adding fclose(pFile); to the end of the code fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to FILE* doesn't write on disk, it writes to user-space buffer.

In order to flush user-space buffer you should call [fflush](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) (or [fclose](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose) that call fflush).

If you want to be sure that data are written to storage device you should call [fsync](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) before fclose.